# heidisql. При импорте нескольких таблиц: Ошибка SQL (1813): Tablespace '`01tst`.`00_tbl_00`' exists

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
MySQL 5,7 - x6,4
Open Server - последний

Папки с БД и таблицами располагались сначала в **ПАПКА 1**.
Я перенастроил сервер, чтобы папки с БД и таблицами располагались в **ПАПКА 2**.

1. Когда сервер работал с папками в  **ПАПКА 1**, я выполнил экспорт базы данных "01tst" с её таблицами.
2. Переключил сервер на **ПАПКА 2**.
3. Выполняю импорт базы данных "01tst" с её таблицами.

***# ПРОБЛЕМА 1***
**ОШИБКА**
При импорте нескольких таблиц: Ошибка SQL (1813): Tablespace '`01tst`.`00_tbl_00`' exists.

Где-то прочитал, что проблему можно убрать

DROP TABLE `01tst`.`00_tbl_00`
или
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `01tst`.`00_tbl_00`

не помогло

В **ПАПКА 2** ("...MySQL-5.7-x64\01tst\") находился файл "00_tbl_00.ibd" и вроде ещё какой-то не обратил внимание... Вроде "db.opt",  но не *.frm...
Я удалил файлы "00_tbl_00.ibd" и "db.opt"(предположительно).

***ПРОБЛЕМА 1. РЕШЕНИЕ 1 (ЧАСТИЧНОЕ)***
1. Импортирую БД.
2. Программа создаёт папку БД с файлами: *.ibd и db.opt.
3. Выдаёт ошибку Пример "Ошибка SQL (1813): Tablespace '`01tst`.`00_tbl_00`' exists." или что-то подобное.
4. Удаляю из директории папку с файлами импортируемой БД, которая выдаёт ошибку.
5. Перезагружаю сервер.
6. Провожу процедуру импорта.
Импортируются все таблицу, все таблицу, но в некоторых таблицах не все строки. 
Около 10-15% строк нет в импортированных таблицах... Ну да ладно... потерплю..

***# ПРОБЛЕМА 2***
Используя решение ***ПРОБЛЕМА 1. РЕШЕНИЕ 1 (ЧАСТИЧНОЕ)*** так добавил три БД.
Потом стала появляться снова ошибка. см .скрин
[image: Скрин **# ПРОБЛЕМА 2**]

Пример кода

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Хост:                         127.0.0.1
-- Версия сервера:               5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Операционная система:         Win64
-- HeidiSQL Версия:              9.4.0.5125
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


-- Дамп структуры базы данных tst_rb_mn_02
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_rb_mn_02` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `tst_rb_mn_02`;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl` (
  `id_tma_ssl` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ssl` text,
  `url_ssl` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl: ~3 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl` (`id_tma_ssl`, `name_ssl`, `url_ssl`) VALUES
    (1, 'name_ssl_04_tbl_zp_1 ', 'url_ssl_04_tbl_zp_1 '),
    (2, 'name_ssl_04_tbl_zp_2 ', 'url_ssl_04_tbl_zp_2 '),
    (3, 'name_ssl_04_tbl_zp_3 ', 'url_ssl_04_tbl_zp_3 ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_01_vr_04_tbl_frm1_ssl` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl` (
  `id_tma_ssl` text,
  `name_ssl` text,
  `url_ssl` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl: ~3 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl` (`id_tma_ssl`, `name_ssl`, `url_ssl`) VALUES
    ('frmA_A', 'name_ssl_07_tbl_zp_1 ', 'url_ssl_07_tbl_zp_1 '),
    ('frmA_B', 'name_ssl_07_tbl_zp_2 ', 'url_ssl_07_tbl_zp_2 '),
    ('frmA_C', 'name_ssl_07_tbl_zp_3 ', 'url_ssl_07_tbl_zp_3 ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_02_vr_07_tbl_frm1_ssl` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl` (
  `id_tma_ssl` text,
  `name_ssl` text,
  `url_ssl` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы tst_rb_mn_02.002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl: ~3 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl` (`id_tma_ssl`, `name_ssl`, `url_ssl`) VALUES
    ('frmA_01', 'name_ssl_10_tbl_zp_1 ', 'url_ssl_10_tbl_zp_1 '),
    ('frmA_02', 'name_ssl_10_tbl_zp_2 ', 'url_ssl_10_tbl_zp_2 '),
    ('frmA_03', 'name_ssl_10_tbl_zp_3 ', 'url_ssl_10_tbl_zp_3 ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `002_tst_03_vr_10_tbl_frm1_ssl` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

**Вопрос.**
1. Как от неё избавиться ошибки - Ошибка SQL (1813)?
2. Как устранить ***# ПРОБЛЕМА 2*** ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просмотреть импортируемые файлы  и убрать скрипты создания сей таблицы во всех кроме первого файла

Comment: @teran Десять против одного, что у него в каталоге БД имеется файл `00_tbl_00.ibd`, и отсутствует файл `00_tbl_00.frm`. Так что убрать создание - не поможет. И удалить `00_tbl_00.ibd` я бы тоже не посоветовал - можно получить ошибку системного пространства имён, а это много хуже, чем сейчас.

Comment: Впрочем, можно попробовать дропнуть tablespace... и если оно дропнется (или выяснится, что сервер не подозревает о его наличии и считает несуществующим) - тогда удаление файла будет гораздо менее опасным делом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите БД перед загрузкой дампа. Или добавьте в начало дампа

```
DROP DATABASE 01tst;
```

В будущем - если дамп делается не для ПОПОЛНЕНИЯ другой БД данными из дампируемой, добавляйте в комстроку mysqldump ключ --add-drop-database.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. '-add-drop-database.'  - как это использовать? Не нашёл синтаксис.. .Просто ввести перед основным кодом?

Comment: _'-add-drop-database.' - как это использовать?_ В точности так, как описано в документации. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database